# How to calculate state and output responses with initial values

Tags: control-theory

**Exercise**

Consider the system $ \dot x = Ax+bu$ with 
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -6 & 2 \\ -6 & 1 \end{bmatrix},~~~ b= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},~~~ c=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Calculate the state and output responses, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, with inital values $x(0)= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T $

**Solution**

The homogeneous time response of the state is
$$ x_{0}(t) = e^{At}x(0) = e^{At} \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2\alpha_0 -10\alpha_1 \\ -11\alpha_1+\alpha_0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6e^{-3t}-4 e^{-2t} \\ 9e^{-3t}-8e^{-2t} \end{bmatrix} $$

While that of the output is
$$y_0(t)=15e^{-3t}-12e^{-2t} $$

**Question**

I do not understand how they jumped from $e^{At} \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix} 2\alpha_0 -10\alpha_1 \\ -11\alpha_1+\alpha_0 \end{bmatrix}$ and to $\begin{bmatrix} 6e^{-3t}-4 e^{-2t} \\ 9e^{-3t}-8e^{-2t} \end{bmatrix}$.

What is $x_0(t)$? How can one control the initial state when the to be regulated process has not started (t=0) yet? Is there a real life example?

How did they get to $y_0(t)$?

Comment: "c" ? $$\\$$ do you mean 
"u" ?

Comment: @Khosrotash, no, it is definitely "c = [1 1]". In control theory the output is defined as y=cx+du. d is often 0. so y=cx

Comment: @autoship So you should already see how they got $y_0(t)$ given the solution $x_0(t)$?

Comment: Just wondering, are you still wondering to the answer of the question or have you already found it out?

Answer (score 0):

First answer is quite long, but eventually boils down to diagonalizing matrix A to a matrix in Jordan form. I can write it out, but I am not sure if you're still looking for the answer?

Short answer to the second question is $y = Cx$, therefore:

$$y_0(t) = Cx_0(t) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_{0_1}(t) \\ x_{0_2}(t)\end{pmatrix}$$